# I need help identificating a gag manga that was serialized around 2003~2004

Tags: kungfu-komang

It's a comedy manga, published around the early 2000's or way before that. The protagonist is an old man (Shifu) with a really long bold head (he often shine it up as one of his "ultimate attack"). He has 3-4 students, I only remember 3 of them with one being a fighter, a ninja and a magician thief (Cased Close, Phantom Kid). I don't know if there are more or not, since I have only seen like 2-3 volumes. Oh, and they're all really poor to the point they'd attend a feast just to eat or they fight each other over a meal. Their reaction to jokes or some events look like they got hit by an upper cut. Also, they tend to play baseball, but always lose miserably.

Answer (score 8):

Fat chance it's [**Kungfu Komang**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=82250).

[image]

[image]

> A boy named Komang learns kung fu and meet many friends along the way.

From the images above, you can spot:

- *an old man with a really long bold head* [you mean bald maybe?]
- *a ninja* [dude with google above his head]
- *a magician thief (Cased Close, Phantom Kid)* [dude with hat and tie in his neck]
- *a fighter* [I think the one you meant by this is Komang, dude in orange suit]

Soooo long since I read it, the only thing I remember is that it's pure comedy, the old man was some kind of a master/teacher (for martial arts?), they all live together, and ruckus happened between them in every story.